# zlib_decode(): data error in Lumen installation

Tags: composer-php, lumen

When I try to install Lumen globally like the following

```
$ composer global require "laravel/lumen-installer=~1.0"
```

I got an error something like the following

> [ErrorException]
>   zlib_decode(): data error

How I can fix it?

Comment: seem like composer issue https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3006

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of poor or interrupted internet connections,In order to solve the problem change your internet form WiFi to Ethernet also  make sure you don't have proxy programs running in background which sometimes interupt, worth to mention: some users might need to enable HTTP checking in setting section of ESET antivirus. Good luck

Comment: yeah, it's just because of poor internet connection.